# Am I entitled to ask my boss about rumours of my transfer?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, communication, manager, politics

I'm working at a rather large company with some relatively intricate politics. I have been here for under a year. My manager as well as others I have worked with have expressed that they are extremely happy with the work I have done so far.

In the past two weeks I have heard whispers from several other people in the company that there is a discussion going on between my boss, a manager horizontal to my boss in the business hierarchy, and their parent manager in the hierarchy. The company wants me to the other manager's team, which has had several employees resign or be let go. The work on this other team is absolutely not what I want to do, and if I am placed on this team I will immediately resign and find work elsewhere. The impression I have received from other people in the company is that my boss is fighting to keep me on his team, but the company feels I am a valuable resource and should be moved to the other team as they are lacking resources on that team.

I haven't heard a word from my boss about this, but apparently it is a very poorly kept secret around our part of the company that this is an ongoing discussion. I am currently debating whether I should talk to my boss about this.

- On one hand, I am working with very incomplete information. I also am not sure what I can expect to change by speaking to my boss about this, I guess I'm just hoping for some reassurance that I'm not being moved. I am not sure if it is a good idea to tell him I will resign if I am transferred to the other team.
- On the other hand, I do feel I have some right to openly discuss things like this with my boss?

Ultimately I'm not sure if this falls under "my business" or not given that I haven't heard any word on the subject from my boss, just rumors from others at the company. Thus I am not sure how it will reflect on me to bring it up with my boss.

Comment: Do you have a good working relationship with your boss?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Yeah, I think he's great and talk about everything else with him. Which makes it even weirder to me that this has not been mentioned to me at all by him.

Comment: Don't take it personally. He may have been instructed not to talk with you about it.

Answer (score 12):

Like others mentioned if you have a good working relationship with your manager, you should be able to ask about it if you catch him at a good time.

A simple "Hey I have been hearing some rumors about a transfer to Y's team. Do you know anything about this?" should suffice. Since this is about the future of your work, yes, it is your business and you should not feel otherwise.

That being said I would not mention any plans to resign if the transfer happens. I would also try making the conversation private instead of bringing it up in company. He may very well have been told not to discuss it and might feel more confident about giving you a heads up if whatever he tells you does not make a tour around the rumor mill.

Comment: You could also add that "I really like working in this team and feel I've settled in well here" just to hint that you don't want to move, which might help your manager fight to have you stay.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a good working relationship with your boss, and these rumours are concerning you, yes, you should have a chat with you boss. Do so in person.

You boss may be able to use your concerns as a bit of leverage, or not, it's up to them.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation but I was the one who wanted to move. Fortunately the upper management that had to approve "letting me take this job offer" realized that it was better to at least keep me as a resource in the company than have me go external for a new position, so my transfer request was allowed with the caveat of "if system X goes crazy we get to borrow him back to fix it all".

If your current direct manager wants to keep you, and is on your side in this whole affair, then perhaps mentioning that you plan to make a quick exit if forced to the other team could help.  It also may help to soften that, and be willing to be "loaned" to the other team for a short period, like 3 or 6 months, so you can assist with keeping things going while new team members are found, and assist with getting them up to speed before returning to your old position.

Otherwise, polish up the resume...